# Where can I find the log files for mounting disks?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, live-cd, log

I understand if I boot from a live cd  I can see all the system logs under **System > Administration > File Log Viewer**

I have a major error with a disk not mounting and I want to trace i tback to the last time it did work and what may have corrupted the ext4 filesystem on it.

So within the **File Log Viewer** Where do I start examining?

Comment: Are you only looking at the logs that were generated by the LiveCD starting up? Or are you looking at the logs on the host filesystem?

Comment: ah you can also just search all the logs from commandline: `cd /var/log/` and do a `grep -R mount *`  (assuming you want to see all lines that contain mount).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd guess `/var/log/dmesg`

You can find all logs that mention mounting or ext4 like this:

```
grep -e mount -e ext4 -lR /var/log 2> /dev/null
```

dmesg seemed to be the most relevant to me. And there are archived versions (dmesg.*).

Answer (score 9):

You can find aditional information in syslog

```
grep 'Mounted' /var/log/syslog*
```

or find mounted and unmounted logs

```
grep 'Mounted\|Unmounted' /var/log/syslog*
```

Comment: I know this has been downvoted because it does not allow to see when a disk has last been successfully mounted (as was asked), but you can still find some interesting debugging info there as why a disk was not mounted or why it was automatically unmounted.

Comment: I am a beginner and somehow this command was easier to use.

Comment: I voted for this response because I didn't find /var/log/dmesg in Ubuntu Studio 18.04.  I did find a mount error code in /var/log/syslog; unfortunately, it didn't reveal anything I didn't already know.