# Does a USB HDD contain info on previous mounts?

Tags: usb-drive, log

I have an external hard drive (usb) , I suspect that it might have been mounted into another computer on a precise date and time.

Is there any way to see the log (from the hdd) and verify if it was mounted in that precise moment or if any file was copied?

Comment: Do you have access to the other computer?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/40471/where-can-i-find-the-log-files-for-mounting-disks  see syslog. But you need access to the other computer.

Comment: I don't have access to the other computer (might be a laptop). From the hdd, isn't it possible to see a log where it just says if on may 3rd between 1pm and 3pm the volume was mounted?

Comment: Nope. Your system logs what happens on your system. Not what happens on another. So all you can prove is that the disk was or was not present in your computer at that time. Not if it was present in another.  Files added to the system would have a timestamp that would fall outside the period the disk was present but there is no easy way to find that out.

Comment: ok thank you. I thought the hdd had its own internal log.

Comment: I apologize in advance for asking: should I open the terminal, writing the string that leads me to the mounted device and then type this:
grep 'Mounted\|Unmounted' /var/log/syslog*

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no.

The hard drive itself will not contain that information.

If you have access to the computer it was previously used with, then `syslog` will have recorded the plug/unplug events.

So you can know whether or not that drive was present on a particular computer.